# Python: Array-based equation

Tags: python

I have a dataframe 500 rows long by 4 columns. I need to find the proper python code that would divide the current row by the row below and then multiply that value by the value in the last row for every value in each column. [I need to replicate this excel formula basically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPX65.png).

Comment: You want to store the values of each row multiplication in another dataframe with 4 columns?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if your data is stored in an array as provided by Numpy, were it true you'd write, with the original data contained in `a`

```
b = a[-1]*(a[:-1]/a[+1:])
```

`a[-1]` is the last row, `a[:-1]` the array without the last row and `a[+1:]` the array without the first (index zero, that is) row

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about pandas DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# sample DataFrame object 
df = pd.DataFrame((float(random.randint(1, 100)),
                float(random.randint(1, 100)),
                float(random.randint(1, 100)),
                float(random.randint(1, 100)))
                for _ in range(10))

def function(col):
    for i in range(len(col)-1):
        col[i] = (col[i]/col[i+1])*col[len(col)-1]

print(df) # before formula apply
df.apply(function)
print(df) # after formula apply

>>>
        0     1     2      3
0  10.0  78.0  27.0   23.0
1  72.0  42.0  77.0   86.0
2  82.0  12.0  58.0   98.0
3  27.0  92.0  19.0   86.0
4  48.0  83.0  14.0   43.0
5  55.0  18.0  58.0   77.0
6  20.0  58.0  20.0   22.0
7  76.0  19.0  63.0   82.0
8  23.0  99.0  58.0   15.0
9  60.0  57.0  89.0  100.0

            0           1           2           3
0    8.333333  105.857143   31.207792   26.744186
1   52.682927  199.500000  118.155172   87.755102
2  182.222222    7.434783  271.684211  113.953488
3   33.750000   63.180723  120.785714  200.000000
4   52.363636  262.833333   21.482759   55.844156
5  165.000000   17.689655  258.100000  350.000000
6   15.789474  174.000000   28.253968   26.829268
7  198.260870   10.939394   96.672414  546.666667
8   23.000000   99.000000   58.000000   15.000000
9   60.000000   57.000000   89.000000  100.000000
```